# Understanding asyncio: Asynchronous vs synchronous callbacks

Tags: python, asynchronous, callback, python-asyncio

There's one very particular thing about `asyncio` that I can't seem to understand. And that is the difference between asynchronous and synchronous callbacks. Let me introduce some examples.

Asyncio TCP example:

```
class EchoServer(asyncio.Protocol):

def connection_made(self, transport):
    print('connection made')

def data_received(self, data):
    print('data received: ', data.decode())

def eof_received(self):
    pass

def connection_lost(self, exc):
    print('connection lost:', exc)
```

Aiohttp example:

```
async def simple(request):
    return Response(text="Simple answer")

async def init(loop):
    app = Application(loop=loop)
    app.router.add_get('/simple', simple)
    return app

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
app = loop.run_until_complete(init(loop))
run_app(app, loop=loop)
```

Those two examples are very similar in functionality but they seem to be both doing it in different way. In the first example, if you want to be notified on some action, you specify a synchronous function (`EchoServer.connection_made`). However, in the second example, if you want to be notified on some action, you have to define an asynchronous callback function (`simple`).

I would like to ask what is the difference between these two types of callback. I understand the difference between regular functions and asynchronous functions, but I cannot wrap my head around the callback difference. For example, if I would want to write an asynchrnonous API like `aiohttp` is, and I would have a function that would do something and call a callback after that, how would I decide if I should demand an asynchronous function to be passed as an argument or just a regular synchronous one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `aiohttp` example you could do asynchronous calls from `simple` web-handler: access to database, make http requests etc.

In `Protocol.data_received()` you should call only regular synchronous methods.

**UPD**

`Protocol` callbacks are supposed to be synchronous by design.
They are very low-level bridge between sync and async. 
You may call async code from them but it requires really tricky coding.
User level `asyncio` API for sockets etc. are streams: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html

When you introduce your own callback system must likely you need asynchronous callback unless you are %100 sure why the callback will never want to call async code.

Regular functions (`def`) and coroutines (`async def`) have a different signatures. It's hard to change a required signature, especially if your code has published as a library and you cannot control all users of your callback.

P.S.

The same is true for any public API methods.

The hardest lesson I've learned during development of my libraries is: `.close()` method **should** be a coroutine even initially it calls sync functions only, e.g. `socket.close()`.

But later you perhaps will want to add a graceful shutdown which requires a waiting for current activity finishing and so on.

If your users had call your api as `obj.close()` now they should use `await obj.close()` but it's **backward incompatible** change!

Comment: However, if I keep reference to the event loop, I can still call asynchronous  methods even in the synchronous ``Protocol.data_received()``, isn't that right?

Comment: You just cannot use `await` in `Protocol.data_received()` but shoutd make a task and wait for task finishing somewhere.

Comment: So it's basically irrelevant, from the perspective of an API whether it exposes a function that requires synchronnous callback or an asynchronnous callback?  Or was there some specific factor that caused the developers of asyncio to strictly require synchronous callbacks in the ``Protocol`` classes?

Comment: I've updated my answer trying to explain my opinion.

Comment: Hey, this is extremely helpful! Thanks! The last thing that bothers me is the UDP protocol. You mentioned that we should be using the ``streams`` API to manipulate with sockets in async manner. But is there some support for making calls like ``await udp.receiveNextDatagram()``?

Comment: Sorry, no.
For working with UDP you should use protocols.
Maybe UDP support will appear in next aiohttp releases but right now there is no use case and desired API is not clear.